# Apply impulse working on x axis but not on y axis

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

First of all a bit of a background. I'm using Cocos2D with Objective C wrapper for Chipmunk as the physics engine. I have a PhysicsNode called actionNode. On the actionNode I have a physics body, called runningFox. The actionNode and runningFox are scrolled in opposite directions to give a notion of endless runner.. It's done in the update method like this:

```
   -(void)update:(CCTime)delta{

    runningFox.position=ccp(runningFox.position.x+actionNodeScrollSpeed*delta, runningFox.position.y);
    actionNode.position=ccp(actionNode.position.x-actionNodeScrollSpeed*delta, actionNode.position.y);
   }
```

When swiped up I get the runningFox jumped up by simply using CCActionJumpBy action. Now when it's in the air and swipe down takes place, I need it to come back to the ground fast as opposed to it's normal landing which is handled by the gravity automatically.While how good practice it is can be argued, for that purpose I tried this method:

```
   [runningFox.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0, 300) atLocalPoint:ccp(0.5, 0.5)];
```

But I don't seen any effect. But if I reverse x and y values like this

```
   [runningFox.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(300, 0) atLocalPoint:ccp(0.5, 0.5)];
```

The body is forced forward. So for some reason the impulse is applied on the x axis, but not on the y axis. So what am I doing wrong?

To be honest, I've read the documentation and didn't quite get what those arguments meant for that method. So, I'm not 100% sure what I should pass in order to get what I need

Comment: i guess manually updating the position of runningFox in update method is colliding with the physics engine trying to update the position of the fox on impulse. Instead of updating the x coordinate in update method, set a velocity in x direction of the runningFox and let chipmunk handle the position update. Applying the impulse after these changes might show the expected outcome.

Comment: You know, I'd be very glad if you could share a little piece of code showing how to do that with velocity.That thing really bugs me down.I mean it's been a source for many problems so far.